# Django: namespacing for flatpages?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

So I am new to Django (and complete the 7 part tutorial) as well as read the [flatpages app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/flatpages/) documentation.

At the end of which, whoever wrote the Django documentation gives a demonstration as to how one would retrieve all the flatpages:

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
<ul>
    {% for page in flatpages %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I now have flatpages working (e.g. if I go to /pages/my_flatpage/ the default template I have renders. as I have included `url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls'))` in the `urlpatterns`.

So I am now in another app of mine and want to link to these flatpages. Using the code above I create the links. However, when I click on them, they do not render as they are routed to `/my_flatpage/` rather than `/pages/my_flatpage/`.

So I tried including the url pattern in my app, but that didnt work. How can I get the to go to the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not hosting the pages directly at the root, the `url` attribute doesn't return the whole path. Instead you should use the URL reversing functionality as with any other object:

```
{% for page in flatpages %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage' page.url %}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```